# Can I let gerrit2 pull from a central git repo automatically and controllable？

Tags: git

For now  gerrit2 holds some proeject's git repo,and as I know these repos are not central git repo.
I just want to know how  to  make gerrit  pulling  from a central git repo automatically,to make the gerrit2 git repo up-to-date.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit Code Review doesn't have automatic pull capability. You'll either have to set up a cronjob somewhere to pull the code from the other source and push it to the Gerrit server or, if possible, set up the other server to push changes to your Gerrit server as updates arrive.